# Why my APK running with different performance on same Android version?

Tags: android, cordova, construct-2

I build a simple game (APK) with Construct 2 + CLI Cordova + Android Studio (target SDK 27, min SDK 21), then test it on two devices :

- Samsung i9082 (Lolipop - cust rom) : Slow performance
- Asus (Lolipop) : Good performance

*Same results when i build it with Phonegapp build.

Its mean old devices no longer supported to run APK with this configuration ? Or there any other explanation / solutions?

Comment: On each device what is the Android System WebView version?

Comment: I have installed latest Google webview from PlayStore. But i9082 use custrom AOSP webview ( if i change to Google webview, the game won't run ). Asus use Google webview.